# Sharepoint - Populate dropdown from a list

Tags: list, dropdown

I have a Sharepoint List called **Volumes** to which I plan to add a column called *providers*. I have a second Sharepoint list called **ProviderList**. I would like for my end user to use to populate the *providers* column in the **Volumes** list with (presumably a dropdown) choices from **ProviderList**.
How can I do this?
If it isn't clear from the nature of my question, I know next to nothing about SharePoint, but find myself needing to support it. I am an SQL developer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Volumes list you can add a new column named Providers.

Then choose the type as look up from another list. Choose Provider List.

[Update](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7a7f9f70-201f-4c0d-a3c4-d3557fc0cec7/lookup-field-missing-columns-in-the-dropdown-list?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy) - Many columns in other lists may not show in lookup list. Some common columns such as ‘id’, ‘version’ etc. can be shown in most cases. When you create a new lookup column and pick a list from the "Get Information from:" option you will only see Single Line of Text columns display in the drop down list.

Comment: Thanks for answering, When I add the column in Volumes as a lookup I do see the Get Information From and I supply Provider List, but it then asks 'In This Column' and the choices are (Title, ID, content Type, Version, Title linked). The columns in Provider List are (Provider Name, title, Created By, Modified By).  I'd like to specify Provider Name, but that doesn't seem to be an option when adding the column in Volumes.

Comment: What is the column type of Provider Name? Can you select Title and check?

Comment: Provider Name is Choice and Title is Single line of Text.

Comment: I got it! thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I changed the column type of Provider Name to single line of text and then it appeared in my list of columns to use in the lookup!